# How to use stack flair on my site?

Tags: widgets, stackoverflow

I want to add stack flair on my WordPress site. How can I use that?

I want to put it in the right hand side column.

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

I think it's pretty self-explanatory, see the SE flair page.
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/flair

Simply copy the provided HTML and paste it into the appropriate template file.

I didn't down vote, but i can understand why, this is really basic copy and paste HTML..

Comment: i got my solution, i didnt jst copy paste the html. i downloaded the widget, uploaded in wp-content/plugin. Then i logged in to my wordpress site , activated the plugin, Then i included my user id to the widget. Then i get the flair in my site. My site is underconstruction. U can view my flair here http://pratikshya.com.np. How can this be just copy and paste?? Thank you for your suggestion.