# How to put Stack Exchange Flair as widget?

Tags: widgets, images

I want to put my flair in as a widget in the top of my sidebar in my blog. There was a similar question asked [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/4891/how-to-use-stack-flair-in-wordpress-site) but the only answer links to the flair page and suggests copying and pasting the html into the theme.

I don't want to edit my theme, I want to be able to add is as a widget. Is this possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### You can add the flair code to a text widget.

[image]

### Then go to your WordPress dashboard Appearance -  > Widgets

[image]

### Your flair in the sidebar[image]

Comment: Just used this!

Answer (score 1):

Just copy and past your flair code into the default text widget.